# node-webrtc: MediaStream not instance of MediaStream, tracks returned by MediaStream.getTracks() not instances of MediaStreamTrack

Tags: node.js, webrtc, node.js-addon

I am trying to develop a fork of [JsSIP](https://github.com/versatica/jssip) that is compatible with Node.js using [node-webrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc), and I've hit a road block.

In my code, I also attempt to clone the track to see if that would solve the problem which it also does not.

Here is my code ([context](https://github.com/hieyou1/JsSIP/blob/b1cde481a780372056e319a21979dfdf294f4ecc/lib/RTCSession.js#L560)):

```js
for (let i of stream.getTracks()) {
    let trackClone = i.clone();
    console.log(i, trackClone, i.constructor, MediaStreamTrack, i.constructor == MediaStreamTrack, i instanceof MediaStreamTrack, stream, stream.getTracks());
    console.log(i instanceof MediaStream);
    this._connection.addTrack(trackClone, stream);
}
```

Expected result in console:
`MediaStreamTrack {} MediaStreamTrack {} [Function: MediaStreamTrack] [Function: MediaStreamTrack] true true MediaStream {} [ MediaStreamTrack {} ]`
`true`

Actual result in console:
`MediaStreamTrack {} MediaStreamTrack {} [Function: MediaStreamTrack] [Function: MediaStreamTrack] false false MediaStream {} [ MediaStreamTrack {} ]`
`false`

This is a problem, because `RTCPeerConnection.addTrack()` does not work on these fake "tracks" or the fake stream.

I think it might be a problem with the stream transferring between files, as before it is passed into this function, `stream instanceof MediaStream = true`.